# how can i display the tab based on select box ng-change using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code to select the country based on ng-options and get tabs based on ng-repeat:

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-options= "countryName.country for countryName in countryNames" ng-change="getCountry()">
</select>

<ul id="configPhoneTab" class="nav nav-tabs equipmentTab agenttabs">
    <li class="active" ng-repeat= "configTab in config" val="configTab[0]">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">{{configTab.tabs}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My tabs in the json file is

```
[
{
 "country": "India",
 "tabs": [
  {
    "title": "India Number",
    "type": [
      "VOICE",
      "FAX",
      "VN"
    ],
    "carrier": "L3",
  },
  {
    "title": "Toll Free",
    "type": [
      "TF"
    ],
    "carrier": "L3",
  }
  ]
},
{
 "country": "Aus",
 "tabs": [
  {
    "title": "Aus Number",
    "type": [
      "VOICE",
      "FAX",
      "VN"
    ],
    "carrier": "L3",
  },
  {
    "title": "Toll Free",
    "type": [
      "TF"
    ],
    "carrier": "L3",
  }
  ]
}
```

How can I retrieve the tabs title from json based on country selection?

Comment: How are your tabs related to countries?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third-party library like `[underscorejs]` ([website address](http://underscorejs.org/)) and retrieve the desired data using some of it's functions for example `_.where(...)` if '_.fined(...)'

the pivot which your search will be based on would be the `$scope.country` which in bound to your `<select>` tag (`<select ng-model="country" ng-options= ...`)

sorry I cannot provide any working demos right away as I'm answering from a mobile device.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I just want to display the data from json array based on my select box options. for example if my select box option is India. I want to get india number and Tollfree tabs with Voice,Fax etc.